# Accessing Kubernetes service converted from Docker Compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I built an application using Docker Compose which included an Nginx instance accepting connections on port 80:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - etc.
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I'd like to spin up this application on Kubernetes running on my local machine (macOS). So I've run `kompose convert`, [documented here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/#kompose-convert).

This generated `nginx-service.yaml` which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.18.0 ()
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I ran `kubectl apply` with all of the YAML files produced by `kompose`, and then `kubectl describe svc nginx`:

```
Name:              nginx
Namespace:         myproject
Labels:            io.kompose.service=nginx
Annotations:       kompose.cmd=kompose convert
                   kompose.version=1.18.0 ()
                   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"kompose.cmd":"kompose convert","kompose.version":"1.18.0 ()"},"creationTimestamp":null,...
Selector:          io.kompose.service=nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                172.30.110.242
Port:              80  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

However, I cannot access the web server by navigating to `http://172.30.110.242:80` on the same machine.

There is documentation on [accessing services running on clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/). I'm new to k8s and I'm not sure how to diagnose the problem and pick the right solution of the options they list.

Is it a defect in `kompose` that it did not generate a comparable service config file?

Comment: Your "connect to" URL from your local machine to a K8 world will not be "172.x.x.x".  It will probably be 192.168.99.100:33333  (port number wil be different).. run this:  minikube service myservicename  -n "default" --url        see what that gives you

Comment: Since you have a ClusterIP service, it’s unreachable from outside the cluster.  NodePort and/or LoadBalancer would be visible from outside; which depends on your specific environment (minikube, Docker Desktop, GKE, EKS, ...)

Answer (score 1):

See:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport

Your "connect to" URL from your local machine to a K8 world will not be "172.x.x.x".  It will probably be 192.168.99.100:33333  (port number wil be different).. run this:

`minikube service myservicename  -n "default" --url`

see what that gives you

but basically, you need to "expose" the k8 world to the outside world.

this yml should help

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: myservicename
  namespace: mycustomnamespace
  labels: 
    name: myservicemetadatalabel
spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: myfirstportname
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80    
  selector: 
    myexamplelabelone: mylabelonevalue
    myexamplelabeltwo: mylabeltwovalue
```

the selector will refer to your pod/container setup.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myfirstpodmetadataname
  namespace: mycustomnamespace
  labels:
    myexamplelabelone: mylabelonevalue
    myexamplelabeltwo: mylabeltwovalue
```

"selectors" is outside scope of this question...but the above will give you the breadcrumb you need

also see:

[How to expose k8 pods to the public internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361841/how-to-expose-k8-pods-to-the-public-internet/48366206#48366206)

Answer (score 0):

You will need an ingress or Nodeport/Loadbalancer service for your service to be accessible from outside.

You can also try to use https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube to convert your docker compose file.

```
move2kube translate -s <folder containing docker compose file>
```

It will ask you which services you like to expose externally, and will create the appropriate ingress yamls for you.