# Kubernetes Pods accessible from outside cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have two Kubernetes clusters. I have run an Nginx server pod on one cluster. Its pod IP is 10.40.0.1. When I ping 10.40.0.1 from this cluster nodes it can ping easily from any node of this cluster.

when I ping from the second cluster node to the first cluster pod it is not working. How should I make a pod so, that it is accessible from the second cluster node as well?

I have deployed Nginx server with the below YAML file.

```
apiVersion: v1     

kind: Pod

metadata:          
  name: Serverpod  
spec:               
  containers:
  - name: Nginx  
    image: nginx:latest 
    ports:               
    - containerPort: 80
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - Node1
```

I have tried the hostnetwork: true but it is not working well.

Comment: I don't think this is something you get out of the box. You would need to either expose your workload externally or run some sort of service mesh to interconnect the clusters.

Comment: I think you should use service with type as NodePort (or LoadBalancer) for external access. I can share the yaml file with you if you need it.

Comment: @vector yes please share with me

Comment: you have few options, please check [How to expose k8 pods to the public internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48366206/9929015)

Answer (score -1):

You have posted a pod spec with `nodeAffinity` in your question which your pod will always run on the `Node1`.

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - Node1
```

If you set `hostNetwork: true`, you can access the pod as `curl <IP of Node1 or just Node1 if the name is resolvable to IP>`. You can also expose the pod via `kubectl expose pod serverpod --type NodePort --name serverpod --port 31000`, in this case you can `curl <any node IP:31000>` and the request will route to your pod by k8s [network proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-proxy). These methods work out of the box that do not require you to install any load balancer, ingress controller or service mesh.

Comment: Using the host network is usually discouraged, especially for Kubernetes pods; you don't control which pod runs on which node and it's very easy to get conflicts.

Comment: Hi @gohm'c =))
I think so.